# PowerBI: Count email subjects by month - assign subject to the month it first appeared

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset similar to the following:

| Email Subject | Date Received | Month Year received |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red | 1 Jan 21 | Jan 21 |
| Blue | 1 Jan 21 | Jan 21 |
| Green | 3 Feb 21 | Feb 21 |
| Red | 5 Feb 21 | Feb 21 |

What I am looking for is a count of distinct email subjects by month however if a subject appears in the previous month then don't count it.

The ideal outcome using the data above would be a:

Total count (No month breakdown) = 3 ( 3 unique subjects - Red, Blue & Green)
Count of subjects for Jan = 2 (Red and Blue)
Count of subjects for Feb = 1 (Only green because Red appeared in the previous month)

This is so I can count how many email threads were received each month without duplicating a thread that spanned over multiple months.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - been stuck for ages!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no date table (if you do, you can adjust the code accordingly), here you go.
[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR month = MONTH(MAX('Table'[Date Received]))
VAR year = YEAR(MAX('Table'[Date Received]))
VAR ddate = MAX('Table'[Date Received])
VAR currentTable = 
    CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[Email Subject]),
        FILTER(ALL('Table'),
        MONTH('Table'[Date Received]) = month && YEAR('Table'[Date Received]) = year)
    )
VAR excludeTable = 
    CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[Email Subject]),
        FILTER(ALL('Table'),
       'Table'[Date Received] < EOMONTH(ddate,-1))
    )
VAR result = EXCEPT(  currentTable,excludeTable)
    
RETURN IF(HASONEVALUE('Table'[Email Subject]),COUNTROWS(result),DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Email Subject]))
```

Comment: Without seeing your full data model, it is impossible to say. Can you share a .pbix. With the input data you have provided, the solution works. Please don't forget to mark as accepted.

Comment: You can upload to an external site of your choice and post a link here. I suggest you also look at some Power BI tutorials as both answers provided work but you will need to incorporate them yourself in your own model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a measure like this

```
Measure =
VAR mxp =
    MAX ( 'Fact'[Month Year received] )
VAR _cp =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Fact'[Email Subject] ),
        'Fact'[Month Year received] = mxp
    )
VAR _ytd =
    CALCULATETABLE (
        VALUES ( 'Fact'[Email Subject] ),
        'Fact'[Month Year received] < mxp
    )
VAR _join =
    COUNTX ( EXCEPT ( _cp, _ytd ), [Email Subject] )
RETURN
    IF (
        HASONEVALUE ( 'Fact'[Month Year received] ),
        _join,
        COUNTROWS ( VALUES ( 'Fact'[Email Subject] ) )
    )
```

**`mxp`** gets what is currently visible to DAX

**`'Fact'[Month Year received] = mxp`** gets only the current month's unique email subjects.

**`'Fact'[Month Year received] < mxp`** gets anything up-to immediately preceding to whatever is currently visible

**`_join`** does a left-anti join that brings whatever unique is visible in the current month.

**`subtotal`** are handled little differently through **`IF(HASONEVALUE('Fact'[Month Year received]),_join,COUNTROWS(VALUES('Fact'[Email Subject])))`**

[image: s1]

Comment: Instead of editing my answer, edit your question with a clear indication of the end result you want to achieve.